# Howto make JRequest::getVar filter correctly accented characters?

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I want to filter some variables with accented character on a component for joomla1.5 for example:

```
$name = JRequest::getVar('name', '', 'post','WORD');
```

but the getvar function filters `áéíóú`. I need this get well for a form in spanish language.

I'm new to joomla development, but for as far as I can see, it doesn't let me set any other parameter to config to get this.

Is there a way to do this with the advantage of filtering with `JRequest::getVar` or should I create a function myself which does so?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean JRequest::getVar() removes symbols like 'áéíóú'? It is very weird because I've worked on Joomla with danish and hebrew symbols. And they were passed through GET, POST, SESSION successfully. Because Joomla works with UTF8 and it understands such symbols. The problem could be only in your file encoding. They should be in UTF8. Is it so? If not try to change it. This should help.